# Xamarin Forms Solution Hangs on Loading Projects in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Upon attempting to open a Xamarin Forms solution in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022, the loading of projects hangs, requiring the deletion of the .vs folder for a successful opening. However, when attempting to reopen the solution after closing Visual Studio, the same issue arises, necessitating the deletion of the .vs folder once more.

[image]

Comment: 0. Running low on disk space? 1. If you make a new solution using XF project template, are you able to build and run that ok? Then close it, and open it again? 2. Do you have access to another PC? To see if it is just this PC that has trouble with this solution. 3. In addition to deleting .vs, be sure to delete all .bin and .obj folders of the solution. 4. You may need to delete all versions of VS from that PC, reboot, then install the current VS again.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General and remove the tick at "Allow parallel project initialization"

[image]